# Solr Suggester not working in sharding (distributed search)

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have two solr server (solr 4.5.1) which is running in shard..

I have implemented solr suggester using spellcheckComponent for auto-suggester.

when i execute suggest url on individual core then the solr suggestion is coming properly.

> mysolr.com:8986/solr/core1/suggest?spellcheck.q=city%20of

and

> mysolr.com:8987/solr/core1/suggest?spellcheck.q=city%20of

when i fired url with refence to solr wiki (wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Distributed_Search_Support) the result is not coming and below exception is occur.

> mysolr.com:8986/solr/core1/select?shards=mysolr.com:8986/solr/core1,mysolr.com:8987/solr/core1&spellcheck.q=city%20of&shards.qt=%2Fsuggest&qt=suggest

java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:843) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:649) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:628) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:311) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:703) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:406) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640) at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

for reference below is my schema.xml and solrconfig.xml entry

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">suggest</str>
  <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
  <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookupFactory</str>
  <str name="field">sugg</str> 
  <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
</lst>
```

```
 <requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
  <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
  <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
```

```
<fieldType name="text_autocomplete" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syn.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
```

i have unique filed, id which is `store = true` in `schema.xml`

can any one please suggest the solution.